# SUM and GROUP BY on multiple fields of JSON data using Linq.js

Tags: jquery, json, linq.js

I have a JSON data and I need to do group by and sum the data. Let's say I have a json object which looks like this:

```
var dataString='[{"Company":"ABC","Focus":"Operate","Completed":"50","Remaining":"25"},{"Company":"ABC","Focus":"Operate","Completed":"20","Remaining":"50"},{"Company":"DEF","Focus":"Optimize","Completed":"100","Remaining":"75"},{"Company":"XYZ","Focus":"Innovate","Completed":"100","Remaining":"75"},{"Company":"ABC","Focus":"Improve","Completed":"50","Remaining":"50"},{"Company":"ABC","Focus":"Optimize","Completed":"50","Remaining":"25"},{"Company":"DEF","Focus":"Operate","Completed":"50","Remaining":"25"},{"Company":"ABC","Focus":"Improve","Completed":"50","Remaining":"25"},{"Company":"XYZ","Focus":"Operate","Completed":"50","Remaining":"25"},{"Company":"XYZ","Focus":"Operate","Completed":"50","Remaining":"25"},{"Company":"XYZ","Focus":"Optimize","Completed":"20","Remaining":"50"}]';
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGeNk.png)

output :: Array inside an array, first array should contain company and inside one more array which will contain my focus area sum of completed and remaining data.

```
Company: 
   1. ABC --Focus -- 1.Operate  -- Completed :70 ,Remaining:75
                     2.Improve    -- Completed:100 ,Remaining:75
                     3.Optimize -- Completed:50 ,Remaining:25

   2. DEF--Focus-- 1.Operate  -- Completed:50 ,Remaining:25
                   2.Optimize -- Completed:100 ,Remaining:75  

   3. XYZ--Focus-- 1.Innovate  -- Completed:100 ,Remaining:75
                   2.Operate    -- Completed:100 ,Remaining:50
                   3.Optimize -- Completed:20 ,Remaining:50
```

I have tried below query to achieve this :

```
  var resultxyz = Enumerable.From(dataString).GroupBy("$.Company", null,
    function (key, g) {
    var resultxyz = {
        z: key,
        totalCompleted: g.Sum("$.Completed"),
        totalRemaining: g.Sum("$.Remaining")

    }
    return resultxyz ;
}).ToArray();
```

But this is grouping only on Company I have to do on focus also.
Any idea or suggestion would be great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you're looking for a two-tiered grouping.  First an overall grouping of all companies, and within each group, a grouping of foci.  There's many different ways this could be modeled, but the most straight forward way:

```
var query = Enumerable.From(data)
    .GroupBy("$.Company", null,
        function (key, g) {
            return {
                Company: key,
                Result: Enumerable.From(g)
                    .GroupBy("$.Focus", null,
                        "{ Focus: $, Completed: $$.Sum('Number($.Completed)'), Remaining: $$.Sum('Number($.Remaining)') }"
                    )
                    .ToArray()
            };
        }
    )
    .ToArray();
```

Note the use of the `Number()` function.  Since the `Completed` and `Remaining` properties are strings, taking the sum will not quite work as expected.  We need to convert them to numbers beforehand.

Comment: Thank you so much Jeff this is exactly what i wanted :) :)